# Getting elements within shadowroots using Powershell and Selenium

Tags: html, powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate clicks in a chrome browser using Powershell and Selenium. So far, I have managed to click elements within the body of the html file - sample below.

**HTML**

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars" class="dropdownContent">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

**Powershell**

```
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="cars"]/option[3]').Click()
```

Using the script above will click the 3rd option that resides within the select element (in this case, "Mercedes").

However, I am struggling in manipulating elements inside Shadow roots, i can't seems to access any elements inside it, what makes it worse is that the element that I would like to click on resides within child shadow roots, as seen in the image below:

[image]

**HTML copy of the above image:**

```
<mds-select class="col-md-3 link-section mds-select--cpo" id="linkCategoryId">
<!--1st Shadow Root, open-->
    <div class="mds-select__label-wrap">
        <label class="mds-select__label mds-select__label--box" id="select-linkCategoryId-label">Object</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mds-select__select-wrap mds-select__select-wrap--vertical-label">
        <div class="mds-select__menu mds-select__menu--hidden">
            <div class="mds-select__menu-list">
                <mds-select-option data-index="0" data-setsize="6" value="Monkey" label="Monkey" selected="false" data-accessible-text-cardinality-separator="of" inactive="false" class="mds-select-option--cpo">
                <!--2nd Shadow Root within, open-->
                
                    <div class="option option--hidden" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="6">
                        <div class="option__label">
                            <span class="option__accessible-text">Monkey</span>
                            <span class="option__label-primary" aria-hidden="true">Monkey</span>
                            <div class="option__slot-container" aria-hidden="true">
                                <slot></slot>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                </mds-select-option>
                
                <mds-select-option data-index="1" data-setsize="6" value="Mochi" label="Mochi" selected="false" data-accessible-text-cardinality-separator="of" inactive="false" class="mds-select-option--cpo">
                <!--2nd Shadow Root within, open-->
                
                    <div class="option option--hidden" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="6">
                        <div class="option__label">
                            <span class="option__accessible-text">Mochi</span>
                            <span class="option__label-primary" aria-hidden="true">Mochi</span>
                            <div class="option__slot-container" aria-hidden="true">
                                <slot></slot>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                </mds-select-option>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</mds-select>
```

Specifically, i would like to click on "Monkey"

I tried using xpath "$ChromeDriver.**FindElementByXPath**('//*[@id="linkCategoryId"]//div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8QWp.png)/div/div/div/mds-select-option[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXsn.png)').Click()"

but I'm just getting an error log that says "Unable to locate element":

[image]

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me, provide tips, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ChromeDriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('#linkCategoryId').shadowRoot.querySelector('mds-select-option[value="Mochi"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('[class="option__accessible-text"]').click()")
```

you should use executeScrit to get the webelement as shadowRoot is not part of the normal DOM

Comment: Thanks for answering, but im getting error: Unexpected token 'Mochi\"]')"' in expression or statement. When i tried executing that script. Also, can it access elements inside Shadowroots of shadow roots and its child roots? Is this possible?

$ChromeDriver.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#linkCategoryId').shadowRoot.querySelector('mds-select-option').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.option option--hidden div.option__label mds-select-option[value=\"Mochi\"]')")")

Comment: you have to escape " , i think instead \" u should do """Mochi"""

Comment: you can also set `$value = '"Mochi"'` and use that instead inside the execute script

Comment: I'm no longer getting any erorrs, but it still doesnt select the value inside the 2nd shadow roots. I tried doing: $ChromeDriver.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#linkCategoryId div.mds-select__menu-list mds-select__menu-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('mds-select-option[value=""$value""]')") without success.

Comment: no it returns that parent element, now you can do like you used to do parent.findelement("option1").click()

Comment: what we have done is to get the element that is inside the shadowroot, now as you have the element you can use it as you used to do in selenium

Comment: updated the code could you try the updated one

Comment: I tried the updated code, but getting an error: tor('#linkCategoryId').shadowRoot.querySelector('mds-select-option[value='Mochi']').shadowRoot.querySelector('[class='option__accessible-text']').click()")
Exception calling "ExecuteScript" with "1" argument(s): "javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)"